# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_110_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (0, 1)

Tags: python, numpy, input, keras

I am trying to make a Traffic Sign detection network but at the learning step I have this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_110_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (0, 1)

here is the code i am using :

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import color, exposure, transform

NUM_CLASSES = 43
IMG_SIZE = 48

input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

def preprocess_img(img):
    # Histogram normalization in v channel
    hsv = color.rgb2hsv(img)
    hsv[:, :, 2] = exposure.equalize_hist(hsv[:, :, 2])
    img = color.hsv2rgb(hsv)

    # central square crop
    min_side = min(img.shape[:-1])
    centre = img.shape[0] // 2, img.shape[1] // 2
    img = img[centre[0] - min_side // 2:centre[0] + min_side // 2,
              centre[1] - min_side // 2:centre[1] + min_side // 2,
              :]

    # rescale to standard size
    img = transform.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))

    # roll color axis to axis 0
    img = np.rollaxis(img, -1)

    return img
from skimage import io
import os
import glob


def get_class(img_path):
    return int(img_path.split('/')[-2])

root_dir = 'GTSRB/Final_Training/Images/'
imgs = []
labels = []

all_img_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(root_dir, '*/*.ppm'))
np.random.shuffle(all_img_paths)
for img_path in all_img_paths:
    img = preprocess_img(io.imread(img_path))
    label = get_class(img_path)
    imgs.append(img)
    labels.append(label)

X = np.array(imgs, dtype='float32')
# Make one hot targets
Y = np.eye(NUM_CLASSES, dtype='uint8')[labels]
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')


def cnn_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     input_shape=(3, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
                     activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
    return model
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = cnn_model()

# let's train the model using SGD + momentum
lr = 0.01
sgd = SGD(lr=lr, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler, ModelCheckpoint


def lr_schedule(epoch):
    return lr * (0.1 ** int(epoch / 10))

batch_size = 32
epochs = 30

cb_lr = LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)
cb_mcp = ModelCheckpoint('model.h5', save_best_only=True)
model.fit(X, Y,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.2,
          callbacks=[cb_lr, cb_mcp])
```

Can you please help me because I can't find how to do it? Thank you

Comment: What's your final definition of "X" and also, what is the shape of X[0]? Also, please paste in a model summary (model.summary())

Comment: conv2d_110 (None, 32, 48, 48)
conv2d_117 (None, 32, 46, 46)
max_pooling2d_53 (None, 32, 23, 23)
dropout_69 (None, 32, 23, 23)
conv2d_118 (None, 64, 23, 23)
conv2d_119  (None, 64, 21, 21)
max_pooling2d_54 (None, 64, 10, 10)
dropout_70 (None, 64, 10, 10)
conv2d_120 (None, 128, 10, 10)
conv2d_121 (None, 128, 8, 8)
max_pooling2d_55 (None, 128, 4, 4)
dropout_71 (None, 128, 4, 4)
flatten_18 (None, 2048)
dense_35 (None, 512)
dropout_72 (None, 512)
dense_36 (None, 43)

Total params: 1,358,155

Comment: What about X[0].shape

Comment: shape(X) ===> <tf.Tensor 'Shape:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>

Comment: Still not sure how you generated your X dataset. Is it not a numpy array?

Comment: add the model summary to the question with proper formatting. From the looks of it the input data is not what you expect. Actually it certainly isn't a (?, 32, 48, 48)  matrix. Check your `preprocess_img` function. Its most likely the culprit here.